# Update context variables using .js. Its possible?

Tags: javascript, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

i'm trying to send a user name to my WCS but i not sure how can i do that using a request. My consersation ask for the user email and use a js script to return a json from my sql server...

I'm doing something like that:

What's your email? // WCS 
caique.rodrigues@test.com //USER
`Just a minute.<script>getUserInformation('caique.rodrigues@test.com');</script>` // WCS
nodeTrue //USER (I sent this after confirmated if the user exist and got the user name.)
`Hi <span id='myText'></span><script>document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML = userName;</script>!` //WCS

I know this is not the best way to do that but it is working. I'm trying to call my js functions using something like "output:{'action':}" (And handle it in my node.js like the 'car dashboard sample'), but, it's possible send a varible from my .js to a conversation context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago. In this case, I used functions for access the context variables on the client side (Using [this](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/issues/65) example from Ashley and accessing the `context`), but, for security issues of some company data, I did need to use custom code in the server-side... And, for this case, you can use the method call for Watson Conversation, and access the `context variables` and creates values with custom code in your favor.

**Something like this:**

```
conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
    data.context.yourValue = returnFromYourDatabase;
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    updateMessage(payload, data, req, res);

  });
});
```

You can see the function `updateMessage`, this call is one example from [IBM Developers](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L70), and this function is used to update the message in every request. You can use this function to set too, because this function get the parameters from the call.

**For example:**

```
function updateMessage(input, response) {
  response.context.yourValue = returnFromYourDatabase;
  var responseText = null;
  if (!response.output) {
    response.output = {};
  } 
}
```

See [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?node#introduction) for Watson Conversation Service using Node.js.

See the [Project](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/) with Node.js by IBM Developers.